# How to set value of text field all at once with a webdriver?

Tags: selenium, cucumber, watir-webdriver, sendkeys

I am using Cucumber, watir-webdriver, page-object, and jruby. I am writing a method in a page class that enters a value into a text area. I am using a generated method in the `page-object` gem that, under the hood, invokes the Watir-Webdriver `set` method, that in turn invokes `send_keys` on the element.

Anyway, the problem for me is I am trying to add a VERY LARGE STRING (in order to test max size stuff for a validateable form object). It's 4000 characters and takes a noticeable amount of time to enter.

It would be great if there were a way to just paste the whole string into the text area at once. **Is there any way to do this** with the technologies I have on hand? These are..
JRuby, watir-webdriver, page-object (which really just delegates to watir-webdriver). I suppose under the hood it's selenium-webdriver that's doing the browser driver interaction in any case.

So far I haven't found a way around ultimately using send_keys which basically sends one key stroke at a time and that's why a huge character string is a pain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could directly set the value of the field using `execute_script`.

Given a page with a textarea:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <textarea></textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

Inputting the textarea with `set` took 6-9 seconds (with Firefox/Chrome):

```
input = 'a' * 4000
browser.textarea.set(input)
```

However, by using `execute_script` to directly set the value, it only took 0.2 seconds:

```
input = 'a' * 4000
field = browser.textarea
browser.execute_script('arguments[0].value = arguments[1];', field, input)
```

Comment: Thanks. It's not a perfect option, but it is definitely an option. Don't know why I didn't think of it -- was using execute_script for something else in the test suite already. Good suggestion.